# Using Google Cloud AutoML Model in react-native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, automl

I want to apply google cloud autoML Model to my react-native application.
There are two descriptions to apply this model - Android and Tensorflow.js
Which model is better to apply react-native?
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tflite-android-tutorial :this is android-tutorial,
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial :and this is tensorflow-js tutorial.

Comment: Do you want remote or local model?

Comment: local model. I tried tensorflow.js but It didn't work